# Prevent visual studio from moving tags and braces in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a report in asp.net MVC.  How do I prevent Visual Studio 2015 from moving the tags and braces when working in the View?

I have already gone to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting and unchecked all 3 of the boxes under General. which stops Visual Studio from moving them when working in the Controller but not the View.

I would prefer Visual Studio to NEVER move any of my curly braces and tags, and let me worry about how it looks.  As it is, it keeps moving tags and curly braces and making it difficult to see nesting and that all items have closing braces.

Comment: Razor views use HTML editor settings, not C#.

Comment: That is what I thought but which setting under HTML do I change to prevent it from moving the tags and braces?